# Product merge layers with Keras functionnal API for Word2Vec model

Tags: python, nlp, keras, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to implement a Word2Vec CBOW with negative sampling with Keras, following the code found [here](https://github.com/abaheti95/Deep-Learning/blob/master/word2vec/keras/cbow_model.py):

```
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100

sentences = SentencesIterator('test_file.txt')
v_gen = VocabGenerator(sentences=sentences, min_count=5, window_size=3,
                       sample_threshold=-1, negative=5)

v_gen.scan_vocab()
v_gen.filter_vocabulary()
reverse_vocab = v_gen.generate_inverse_vocabulary_lookup('test_lookup')

# Generate embedding matrix with all values between -1/2d, 1/2d
embedding = np.random.uniform(-1.0 / (2 * EMBEDDING_DIM),
                              1.0 / (2 * EMBEDDING_DIM),
                              (v_gen.vocab_size + 3, EMBEDDING_DIM))

# Creating CBOW model
# Model has 3 inputs
# Current word index, context words indexes and negative sampled word indexes
word_index = Input(shape=(1,))
context = Input(shape=(2*v_gen.window_size,))
negative_samples = Input(shape=(v_gen.negative,))

# All inputs are processed through a common embedding layer
shared_embedding_layer = (Embedding(input_dim=(v_gen.vocab_size + 3),
                                    output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM,
                                    weights=[embedding]))

word_embedding = shared_embedding_layer(word_index)
context_embeddings = shared_embedding_layer(context)
negative_words_embedding = shared_embedding_layer(negative_samples)

# Now the context words are averaged to get the CBOW vector
cbow = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1),
              output_shape=(EMBEDDING_DIM,))(context_embeddings)

# Context is multiplied (dot product) with current word and negative
# sampled words
word_context_product = merge([word_embedding, cbow], mode='dot')
negative_context_product = merge([negative_words_embedding, cbow],
                                 mode='dot',
                                 concat_axis=-1)

# The dot products are outputted
model = Model(input=[word_index, context, negative_samples],
              output=[word_context_product, negative_context_product])

# Binary crossentropy is applied on the output
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')
print(model.summary())

model.fit_generator(v_gen.pretraining_batch_generator(reverse_vocab),
                    samples_per_epoch=10,
                    nb_epoch=1)
```

However, I get an  error during the merge part because Embedding layer is a 3D tensor while cbow is only 2 dimensions. I assume I need to reshape the embedding (which is [?, 1, 100]) to [1, 100] but I can't find how to reshape with the functional API.
I am using the Tensorflow backend.

Also, if someone can point to an other implementation of CBOW with Keras (Gensim free), I would love to have a look to it!

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cbow.py", line 48, in <module>
    word_context_product = merge([word_embedding, cbow], mode='dot')
    .
    .
    .
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,1,100], [?,100].
```

Comment: Can you show the error

Comment: Sure, sorry. Totally forgot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,1,100], [?,100].
```

Indeed you need to reshape the `word_embedding` tensor. Two ways to do it :

- Either you use the `Reshape()` layer, imported from `keras.layers.core`, this is done like :

  ```
  word_embedding = Reshape((100,))(word_embedding)
  ```

  the argument of `Reshape` is a tuple with the target shape.
- Or you can use `Flatten()` layer, also imported from `keras.layers.core`, used like this :

  ```
  word_embedding = Flatten()(word_embedding)
  ```

  taking nothing as an argument, it will just remove "empty" dimensions.

Does this help you?

**EDIT :**

Indeed the second `merge()` is a bit more tricky. The `dot` merge in Keras only accepts tensors of the same rank, so same `len(shape)`.
So what you will do is use a `Reshape()` layer to add back that 1 empty dimension, then use the feature `dot_axes` instead of `concat_axis` which is not relevant for a `dot` merge.
This is what I propose you for the solution :

```
word_embedding = shared_embedding_layer(word_index)
# Shape output = (None,1,emb_size)
context_embeddings = shared_embedding_layer(context)
# Shape output = (None, 2*window_size, emb_size)
negative_words_embedding = shared_embedding_layer(negative_samples)
# Shape output = (None, negative, emb_size)

# Now the context words are averaged to get the CBOW vector
cbow = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1),
                     output_shape=(EMBEDDING_DIM,))(context_embeddings)
# Shape output = (None, emb_size)
cbow = Reshape((1,emb_size))(cbow)
# Shape output = (None, 1, emb_size)

# Context is multiplied (dot product) with current word and negative
# sampled words
word_context_product = merge([word_embedding, cbow], mode='dot')
# Shape output = (None, 1, 1)
word_context_product = Flatten()(word_context_product)
# Shape output = (None,1)
negative_context_product = merge([negative_words_embedding, cbow], mode='dot',dot_axes=[2,2])
# Shape output = (None, negative, 1)
negative_context_product = Flatten()(negative_context_product)
# Shape output = (None, negative)
```

Is it working? :)

The problem comes from the rigidity of TF regarding the matrix multiplication. Merge with "dot" mode calls the backend `batch_dot()` function and, as opposed to Theano, TensorFlow requires the matrix to have the same rank : [read here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul).

Comment: I does help for the first merge yes, thanks a lot! But I get the same kind of error for the second one which I can't fix with a flatten or reshape because the shape of `negative_samples` is (5,) and not (1,): `ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,5,100], [?,100].`
What I don't get is that this code works well with Theano but not with Tensorflow..

Comment: I does work, thank you so much! And thanks for the clarification, I don't know anything about Theano!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help with this one :)